# MySQL - Insert a query into connection string

Tags: mysql, visual-studio, datasource

So recently, after trying out all the possible database services and programming languages, I found out that my best way would be to combine MySQL with VB.NET, of course in Visual Studio.

So, having my MySQL hosted on a external server, all working fine and perfect, double checked with WorkBench, I go on into adding a DataSource with the Connection Wizard, and get a `unexpected error`, which I know why it happens.

It is because whenever I execute a query, all with the most updated versions of MySQL Server, Workbench etc. and Visual Studio, I always have to specify a `use database`, so in reality any query would look like this:

```
use dbmt_students;
select * from students;
```

During the setup wizard, and even after searching the whole possible internet, I couldn't find a solution into actually inserting a query into a connection string, which I also understand may be an security issue, however, I wanted to ask the pros if they know off anything, in such a way that would be help me finish successfully the connection wizard.

Comment: The database to use is specified in the connection string. What is your connection string and what is your database name?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the database in your connection string like this:
"server=127.0.0.1;uid=root;pwd=12345;database=dbmt_students"
There are more examples at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-programming-connecting-connection-string.html